# Responsive charts.js acting weird

Tags: javascript, charts, responsive-design, chart.js, responsive

I'm trying to use Charts.js for the first time,
& have included the option of responsive as one of the parameters,
however its acting kind of weird. I have changed the font size
of the legend labels from the default 12/16 to 22,
So that it is more ledgeable, but I cannot seem to change the font size of the chart (Radar) point labels, i have read the documentation but its not doing anything.
my js is below;

```
// ::..>> React Js Script here.......................................>> Block 1..
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Kaushan Script";
 // Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = "19";

let ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
// Gradient 1.
let gradientX = ctx1.createLinearGradient(220, 345, 478, 222);
    gradientX.addColorStop(0,   'rgba(3, 252, 157, 0.4)');
    gradientX.addColorStop(0.7, 'rgba(5, 99, 132, 0.5)');
    gradientX.addColorStop(1,   'rgba(48, 33, 172, 0.6)');
// Gradient 2.
let gradientY = ctx1.createLinearGradient(220, 345, 478, 222);
    gradientY.addColorStop(0,   'rgba(3, 252, 192, 0.2)');
    gradientY.addColorStop(0.7, 'rgba(5, 244, 148, 0.3)');
    gradientY.addColorStop(1,   'rgba(48, 202, 112, 0.4)');

        let chart = new Chart(ctx1, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'radar',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: [
                    'Tickets\nCreated',
                    'Current\nProjects',
                    'Bug\nBounties',
                    'Issues\nSolved',
                    'Active\nMembers',
                    'Online\nUsers',
                    'Completed\nProjects'
                    ],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Current Stats',
                    backgroundColor: gradientX,// 'rgba(3, 252, 157, 0.9)', // Old Color ::>> 'rgba(5, 99, 132, 0.7)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(252, 186, 3, 0.8)',
                    data: [4, 12, 18, 2, 22, 11, 27],
                    },{
                     label: 'User',
                     backgroundColor: gradientY,// 'rgba(3, 252, 157, 0.9)',    // Old Color ::>> 'rgba(5, 99, 132, 0.7)',
                     borderColor: 'rgba(201, 8, 166, 0.8)',
                     data: [44, 9, 18, 33, 4, 2, 27],
                     }]
            },
// ::..>>   Configuration options go here...................................
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                datasetStrokeWidth : 3,
                pointDotStrokeWidth : 4,
                tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)", // Change this.
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    labels: {
                        fontSize: 28
                    }
                }
            },

            plugins: [{     // This Plugin is Solely for chart.js to recognise \n characters
                beforeInit: function (chart) {
                    chart.data.labels.forEach(function (e, i, a) {
                        if (/\n/.test(e)) {
                            a[i] = e.split(/\n/)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }]              // End of Plugin.........
        });
```

Also its being responsive but in a somewhat awkward manner. on large screen 2560x1440 it looks ok, when it scaled down to mobile the fonts go massive & the chart is a tiny blip in the middle. If i resize my browser from fullscreen to mobile, writing starts off small, then gets bigger, then goes small & finally on mobile size goes massive. is there a way to set min-max size of the chart similar to css..
* Or set min-max value for the legend text, as this seems to be what is displacing everything else and making the chart tiny.

I do not currently have any media query's (of my own) attached to this section containing the chart.js so I don't understand its odd behaviour.
ps. its containing div or section is a square using css 
calc(428.8px + 2vw); Which is responsive. same for height but with "vh"...

Any suggestions?